# How to implement non-allocating placement new in a freestanding program

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

What is the correct way to implement non-allocating placement new in a program that does not use the standard library? The draft standard says that the non-allocating forms are not "displaceable" (https://eel.is/c++draft/new.delete#placement-1):

> These functions are reserved; a C++ program may not define functions that displace the versions in the C++ standard library ([constraints]). The provisions of [basic.stc.dynamic] do not apply to these reserved placement forms of operator new and operator delete.

From my reading, it seems that there is a small difference between non-allocating `operator new` and other overloads because the standard seems to justify the compiler assuming that all overloads of `operator new` declare memory that is aligned to the strictest fundamental alignment (https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.new#note-10), though there seems to be some debate as to whether this is necessary for types that are smaller than the strictest fundamental alignment (but I lost my citation for this).

Is there any clarification on how this should be done?

Two proposals that I have come across:

1. Since you are not including the standard library, you can explicitly declare `void* operator new(size_t, void* p) noexcept { return p; }` which conforms to the specification of the library function in the standard.
2. You overload the `operator new` for each class type that you use it for and are prevented from performing non-allocating new for primitive types.

Comment: Freestanding implementations are still required to have some headers (https://eel.is/c++draft/compliance#2). `<new>` Is still there and contains those declarations. So either this question is moot, or if one insists on "no standard library", then it's no longer a language lawyer question really, since we are outside the standard's purview now.

Comment: If you're not using the standard library you're deep into non-conforming mode. You're already ignoring the standard, so do whatever works.